# Xcode compiler errors delay

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Does anyone know why my compiler errors are showing up after 4 or more seconds delay in Xcode? This is also happening in empty project. I tired to remove caches, reset xcode to "factory settings"  using`defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode` .

Comment: What version of Xcode?

Comment: Version of XCode: 13.4